# Logarithmic equations [Solve for x]

Tags: logarithms

The number of solutions of the equation $$3x^{\log(2)/\log(5)} + 2^{\log(x)/\log(5)} = 64$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=x^{\frac{\log2}{\log5}}$, then

\begin{align}
\log a&=\left(\frac{\log 2}{\log 5}\right)\log x\\
\end{align}

If $b=2^{\frac{\log x}{\log5}}$, then

\begin{align}
\log b&=\left(\frac{\log x}{\log 5}\right)\log 2\\
&=\log a
\end{align}

Hence $a=b$.

The equation can be written as

\begin{align}
3a+a&=64\\
a&=16\\
\log a&=\log 16\\
\log x&=\frac{\log 16\log 5}{\log 2}\\
&=4\log 5\\
x&=625
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that:

> $$x^{\log_5 2} = 2^{\log_5 x}$$

Answer (score 0):

simplifying your equation we obtain
$$2^{\frac{\log (x)}{\log (5)}}-16=0$$ from here we get
$$\log(x)=\log(625)$$ thus $$x=625$$